# How to call POST method in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, npm

I am trying to learn REST API. I created POST method but it is not working
get method is working fine in postman but post method is not working. Can anyone help me where I am missing?
I am stuck in it.
here is my code

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect to mongoose
Genre =require('./models/genre');
Book =require('./models/book');

// Connect to Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore',{ useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Please use /api/book or /api/genres');
});

app.get('/api/genres', (req, res) => {
    Genre.getGenres((err, genres) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(genres);
    });
});


 app.post('/api/genres', (req, res) => {
    var genre = req.body;
    Genre.addGenre(genre, (err, genre) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.json(genre);
    });
}); 



app.listen(3000);
console.log("running on port 3000..");
```

models/genre.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Genre Schema
const genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    create_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);

// Get Genres
module.exports.getGenres = (callback /* we can access through routes*/, limit) => {
    Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);
}

//add genre



 module.exports.addGenre = (genre, callback) => {
    Genre.create(genre, callback);
}
```

get method is working fine in postman but post method is not working. Can anyone help me where I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Did it work????

Comment: yes.. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your code accordingly:

Add in **app.js**:

```
// BodyParser middleware
const BodyParser = require(`body-parser`);
// Create application/json parser
App.use(BodyParser.json({ limit: `50mb` })); // Set request size

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
App.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: `50mb`, extended: true }));
```

Update API call:

```
app.post('/api/genres', (req, res) => {
    var genre = req.body;
    Genre.addGenre(genre, (err, genreDB) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.status(200).send(genreDB);
    });
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `req.body` in your POST handler, you'll need to use some [express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to actually parse the request body. For example, for parsing JSON bodies, you'll need [express.json](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) middleware.